# How would one go about to measure differences in clock time on two different devices?

Tags: timer, timestamp, synchronization, latency

I'm currently in an early phase of developing a mobile app that depends heavily on timestamps.

A master device is connected to several client devices over wifi, and issues various commands to these. When the client devices receive commands, they need to mark the (relative) timestamp  when the command is executed.
While all this is simple enough, I haven't come up with a solution for how to deal with clock differences. For example, the master device might have its clock at 12:01:01, while client A is on 12:01:02 and client B on 12:01:03. Mostly, I can expect these devices to be set to similar times, as they sync over NTP. However, the nature of my application requires ms precision, so therefore I would like to safeguard against discrepancies.

A short delay between issuing a command and executing the command is fine, however an incorrect timestamp of when that command was executed is not.

So far, I'm thinking of something along the line of having the master device ping each client device to determine transaction time, and then request the client to send their "local" time. Based on this, I can calculate what the time difference is between master and client. Once the time difference is know, the client can adapt its timestamps accordingly.
I am not very familiar with networking though, and I suspect that pinging a device is not a very reliable method of establishing transaction time, since a lot factors apply, and latency may change.

I assume that there are many real-world settings where such timing issues are important, and thus there should be solutions already. Does anyone know of any? Is it enough to simply divide response time by two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One heads over to [RFC 5905](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt) for NTPv4 and learns from the folks who really have put their noodle to this problem and how to figure it out.

Or you simply make sure NTP is working properly on your servers so that you don't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I'll check it out!